# How to prevent gmail contacts in ContentResolver.query() in android?

Tags: android

Actually i m trying to display all contacts from my android phone to a custome listview using baseadapter. But when list displays the gmail contacts also displays. And in actual i want to display only Name and Numbers from my contact of phone not gmail or any other. I have pase following query : 
     cursor = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

Please help me........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
  null, 
  ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1", // 1=local, 0=google acount
  null, 
  null
);
```

good luck = =